# How to get the timezone offset for the known timezone string?

Tags: python, datetime, time, timezone, geoip

I'm using pygeoip package to get the timezone for an IP,

```
>>> import pygeoip
>>> gi = pygeoip.GeoIP('GeoIPCity.dat')
>>> gi.time_zone_by_addr('64.233.161.99')
'America/Los_Angeles'
```

Is there any packages that can provide the timezone as
`PST UTC -8:00 America/Los_Angeles` 
Or anything similar in content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `pytz` library is what you need: http://pytz.sourceforge.net/